# cannot open source file "d3dx9.h" error

Tags: c++, directx

I have the directx sdk from june 2010 installed but I still get this error! Could anyone help me? I am using visual studio 2012. I've tried to reinstall it, include the whole directx sdk in my project but I'm still seeing the same error! Please help me out as I'd like to know how to fix this as it's making me behind on a current project that I'm working on, so if anyone can help me out here I'd be extremely appreciative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Missing files, DirectX SDK (d3dx9.lib, d3dx9.h)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17015088/missing-files-directx-sdk-d3dx9-lib-d3dx9-h)

Comment: I've tried all of that and nothing has worked

Comment: Does the file exist in the location given in the previous answer?

Comment: Yes, and I've linked everything in the project properties

Comment: Then you have set the include path for your project incorrectly.

Comment: Where do I set it then?

Comment: To wherever d3dx9.h is! This is not rocket science.